# Prevent Default of a <Link> component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do I prevent default (event.preventDefault()) of a Link component in React if certain state changes, for example, if this.state.isActive is false, when I click the link, nothing happens. See code below:

```
`import { Link } from 'react-router';

  return (
     <div>
       {<Link to={link}>
           <img src={someImageUrl} alt={someImageName} />
       </Link>}
     </div>
);`
```

I am using React version 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by passing an `onClick` function to the element wrapped inside the `<Link />` tag:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

  const prevent = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      // do whatever
  }

  return (
     <div>
       {<Link to={link}>
           <img src={someImageUrl} alt={someImageName} onClick={prevent}/>
       </Link>}
     </div>
);
```

EDIT: I misunderstood the question

Here is the real solution:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

  const link = isActive ? "/somePath" : null

  return (
     <div>
       {<Link to={link}>
           <img src={someImageUrl} alt={someImageName} />
       </Link>}
     </div>
);
```

Comment: The real solution where const link = isActive ? "/somePath" : null is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give a onClick function to the `Link` **Yes it is possible**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

 const isActive = false;

 customFunction(){
   if(isActive){
    this.prop.history.push(link)
  }
 }

  return (
     <div>
       {<Link onClick={customFunction}>
           <img src={someImageUrl} alt={someImageName} />
       </Link>}
     </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to behave like a link at all, you can conditionally render it as a link or a span. For example:

```
{this.state.isActive ? (<Link to={link}>...</Link>):(<span>...</span>)}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind having a link that doesn't go anywhere, you can do:

```
<Link to={this.state.isActive ? link : '#'}>...</Link>
```